# Using assume_role to connect to dynamodb using boto3 in databricks python notebook is giving NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, databricks

I am trying to connect to dynamodb using boto3 with assume_role on databricks.

Here is the example code where I am getting error

```py
%pip install boto3

import boto3

sts_client = boto3.client("sts")

# Getting error here
credentials = sts_client.assume_role(
    RoleArn="arn:aws:iam::<account id>:role/<role name>",
    RoleSessionName="test"
)

session  =  boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id=credentials["Credentials"]['AccessKeyId'], aws_secret_access_key=credentials["Credentials"]['SecretAccessKey'], aws_session_token=credentials["Credentials"]['SessionToken'])

dynamodb = session.client("dynamodb")

dict = dynamodb.scan(TableName='table_name', Limit=1)
```

I am getting error:

```
NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials
```

How to resolve?

Comment: Did you log `credentials` to make sure the values were correct?

Comment: getting error on credentials line itself

Comment: Where do you obtain your credentials to call the STS service?